# What happened to Force.com editions

Tags: force.com, force

I don't know if this topic has been already discussed here, or if this is the right place to be discussed. I would like to ask for an explanation what is exactly Force.com platform is and are there any Salesforce editions, that provide just the functionalities of Force.com platform? I have researched that there were licenses, which provides these functionalities like Force.com One App & Platform Licenses or Force.com Light & Enterprise Licenses. Could you please tell me if these licenses are deprecated and if that's the case are there another license types today, that could replace them. I have been told that for fully Force.com functionalities I have to use Salesforce Platform license. Is the same as the license types, that I have mentioned above. I will be grateful If you cloud provide me some useful official links on this topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Current Salesforce User license information can be found by the following links:

- [User
  Licenses](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=users_understanding_license_types.htm&type=5)
- [Standard User
  Licenses](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=users_license_types_available.htm&type=5)